# FormData to object with nested object-property (Pure JS)

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript, serialization

I have a form which I need to have converted into an javascript object to be proceeded further.

The ouput of the form using

```
var theForm = ev.target as HTMLFormElement;

var formData = new FormData(theForm);
for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(`${pair[0]}, ${pair[1]}`);
}
```

leads to the following

```
firstName, test
lastName, user
nickName, nickname
socialMedia[0]["id"], 2501A153-2940-4A5D-91BD-A1A9537A3E69
socialMedia[0]["url"], https://www.facebook.com/someuser
socialMedia[1]["id"], 5499E656-4151-4B5A-914E-3159865B9B49
socialMedia[1]["url"], https://www.twitter.com/someuser
```

and these are the class-definitions this needs to be converted to:

```
class PlayerObject {
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    nickName?: string;
    socialMedia?: SocialMediaObject[];
}

class SocialMediaObject {
    id?: string;
    url?: string;
}
```

My problem are the nested objects (`SocialMediaObject` in this case). The final object should look like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "user",
    "nickName": "nickname",
    "socialMedia": [
        {   
            "id": "2501A153-2940-4A5D-91BD-A1A9537A3E69",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/someuser"
        },
        {
            "id": "5499E656-4151-4B5A-914E-3159865B9B49",
            "url": "https://www.twitter.com/someuser"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is no framework I can use. So it must be pure js.

Is there any way maybe with using `JSON.stringify/parse`? 
Should the names be set differently, e.g. `socialMedia[0].url` or `socialMedia.0.url`

Comment: i guess your "Object" is fine as it is, what is the output when you console.log(formData )?

Comment: @Benjamin `console.log(formData)` will not show very much. It makes only sense when looping through the `entries()` which is shown in the question. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: oh i see, anyway what about console.log(formData.entries() )?

Comment: Still the same. This will log an `Iterator {}` but will show no data. The data is shown in the question as key-value pairs. I need to convert `socialMedia[0]["url"]` into a nested property

Comment: How about the spread operator?  "console.log(...formData.entries());" you than can use "reduce" to generate an object maybe?